# How to construct block matrix with shadowed entries?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, amsmath, matrices, tikz-matrix

Is there a *simple* way of drawing matrices with shadowed blocks like the ones in the picture?

[image]

I've tried something like [Gonzalo Medina's proposal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191240/9823):

```
%% with these packages loaded
%% \usepackage{tikz}
%% \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Other matrix groups}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Upper triangular $UT(p,q)$:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=.5ex,text height=2ex,text width=1em}]
      \matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells]
              {
                |[fill=black]| a  & |[fill=black]| b \\
                |[fill=white]| 0  & |[fill=black]| c \\
              };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

However, I get an error

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options
>
> l.307 \end{frame}

nonstop compilation yields

> [image]

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: What did you try/see so far that you consider to be _not simple enough_?

Comment: where are the shadows?

Comment: Something like [vertical lines in matrix using tikz package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79166/vertical-lines-in-matrix-using-tikz-package/79188#79188)? To put delimiters around these matrices use the optional arguments `left delimiter=(,right delimiter=\}` etc.

Comment: @PaulGessler I found some examples with lots of `TikZ` style definitions, but I found some simpler examples... so I edit the question because I get an error.

Comment: @percusse Shadowed entries = entries with a pattern of lines. ;-P

Comment: @Andrew Yes, something like that! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: if using beamer `ampersand replacement=\&` and use `\&` in the matrix